# c# file copy to a server

Tags: c#, pdf, file-copying

I want to copy a pdf to my own server but i get an error about path.

the codes like that:

```
string filepath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(open.FileName);
```

when i pick the pdf I want to save it to my server with this codes:

```
string filename = "New name" + ".pdf";
string newpath = @"\\WDMyCloud\Certificates\" + filename;
File.Copy(filepath, newpath, true);
```

But when i run this code i take an error like "invalid path name.

Comment: `File.Copy(filepath, newpath, true);` ?

Comment: What are `name` and `ftpfullpath`? Also did you forget some variable in your new filename? Right now every file you copy gets the same name and and because you overwrite, you lose every pdf apart from the recent one. Do not use `+` to combine paths, use `Path.Combine()`

Comment: is this an ftp or a shared folder? which value has ftpfullpath?

Comment: Sorry about this mistake @sommmen . I want to write the codes here so simple to be understandable

Comment: I write the name and ftpfullpath wrongly. I just write the codes so simple to be undestandable. I use different file names but here i just write "new file". 
I use Path.Combine() but i take the error again.

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu this is an local server in our company.

Comment: Have you checked if filepath and newpath exists and are accessible? doesn't seem a security issue...your code seems ok. Are you leting spaces in the filename??

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu Yes. I checked the filepaths are exists and accessible. There is no space in the filename.